# log4net Remove new line characters from logs

Tags: log4net

We are currently using log4net with the ConsoleAppender. The app runs inside a Docker container, and the console output is sent to our cloud provider (AWS CloudWatch) where we troubleshoot, look at errors, etc.

The problem is when there's multiple lines being sent to the console (think Exception stack traces). Each line is sent to CloudWatch as separate lines, and CloudWatch interprets each line as a separate entry, which looks messy. Ideally I want one CloudWatch entry per log4net LogEntry, or one line at a time per LogEntry in the console output.

In order to do this I would have to remove all line breaks when formatting the LogEntry, maybe escaping it with a "\n\r\" or just a space.

What's the best way to get this behavior in log4net?

Comment: Scratch this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993416

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape newline characters in the message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993416/how-to-escape-newline-characters-in-the-message)